# JSON filtering by time

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON like this

```
[{
    "Event_code": "AB-001",
    "Interest_area": "Arts and Education",
    "Start_time": "9:00 AM",
    "End_time": "3:00 PM",
    "Session_type": "Course information session"
}, {
    "Event_code": "AB-002",
    "Interest_area": "Arts and Education",
    "Start_time": "12:30 PM",
    "End_time": "1:00 PM",
    "Session_type": "Course information session"
}, {
    "Event_code": "AB-003",
    "Interest_area": "",
    "Start_time": "9:00 AM",
    "End_time": "3:00 PM",
    "Session_type": "Course information session"
}, {
    "Event_code": "AB-004",
    "Interest_area": "Business",
    "Start_time": "10:30 AM",
    "End_time": "11:00 AM",
    "Session_type": "Course information session"
}, {
    "Event_code": "AB-005",
    "Interest_area": "General Interest",
    "Start_time": "9:30 AM",
    "End_time": "1:30 PM",
    "Session_type": "Experience"
}, {
    "Event_code": "AB-006",
    "Interest_area": "Environment ,    Business       ",
    "Start_time": "11:00 AM",
    "End_time": "11:30 AM",
    "Session_type": "Course information session"
}]
```

How do I filter this JSON to get events with "**Start_time**" after 12 noon ? I am thinking of doing something like

```
let filtered_data = data.filter(o => o.Start_time >= '12 PM');
```

But of course this will not work as "Start_time" is 'string' and not 'date' type.

Comment: Convert it all to 24 hour time to make it simpler and then filter based on comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have a JSON there - you have an array of objects. JSON is a *particular way of formatting a string to represent an object*.

Luckily, in your case, it should be very easy - to filter for events after 12 noon, you can simply check the `Start_time` property to see if the string includes `PM`:

```js
const input=[{"Event_code":"AB-001","Interest_area":"Arts and Education","Start_time":"9:00 AM","End_time":"3:00 PM","Session_type":"Course information session"},{"Event_code":"AB-002","Interest_area":"Arts and Education","Start_time":"12:30 PM","End_time":"1:00 PM","Session_type":"Course information session"},{"Event_code":"AB-003","Interest_area":"","Start_time":"9:00 AM","End_time":"3:00 PM","Session_type":"Course information session"},{"Event_code":"AB-004","Interest_area":"Business","Start_time":"10:30 AM","End_time":"11:00 AM","Session_type":"Course information session"},{"Event_code":"AB-005","Interest_area":"General Interest","Start_time":"9:30 AM","End_time":"1:30 PM","Session_type":"Experience"},{"Event_code":"AB-006","Interest_area":"Environment ,    Business       ","Start_time":"11:00 AM","End_time":"11:30 AM","Session_type":"Course information session"}];

console.log(
  input.filter(({ Start_time }) => Start_time.includes('PM'))
);
```

Note that `includes` is an ES6 function, you may want a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

Comment: Great solution @CertainPerformance, Quick question ...If I had to found events that are "All day" i.e. at-least 6 hour events, how do I do that ?

Comment: @Slyper I would use Moment.js to compare the differences between the `Start_time` and `End_time`.